# SAML SSO - How SSO works with SAML

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

I know how SAML works and i know how SSO works. My understanding of SSO is that IDP creates a cookie in IDP domain (and other domains can not access the cookie) and uses it to authenticate user.

SAML protocol itself doesn't talk anything about SSO. I get confused when they mix SAML with SSO. For eg : IDP initiated SSO etc.

As per my understanding SSO is implemented independent of SAML (using cookie). Please correct me if i'm missing something.

Comment: SAML is a technology to achieve SSO for Web application without the use of cookies.
SAML does not specify how authentication is achieved at the IdP and it also does not specify how the IdP determines that a user was already authenticated at the IdP.

Comment: Thanks Bernhard. Can you please elaborate this "SAML is a technology to achieve SSO for Web application" ? SAML is mainly used for authenticating to third party app. How SAML can help in achieving SSO among multiple apps ?

Comment: Now i understand what you meant. Instead of idp sharing its cookie (or some session), it gives back SAML. So it is kind of using SAML for SSO.

Comment: Yes, SAML is about exchanging Assertions about an authenticated subject. For this SAML messages are interchanged using specified protocol bindings. Using cookies to achieve SSO has some sustantial backdraws.